# Copy fields from T1 field A to T2 field A where(if or when) T1 field B = T2 field B (mysql)

Tags: mysql

I think I´ve seen a few answers to this question that may not be far from what I need but I don´t know enough about mysql to be sure, so I´ll ask the question for my exact situation.

I have a database with several tables, for this I just need to copy a value from table "images" to table "credits" if the image_media_file column value on "image" table is the same as the credit_file_name column value on "credits" table.

[image: Example]

In this example above the names john and mike would be copied. the remaining would´t.

I was going to use the mysql code on phpmyadmin.

Note:
It is possible that there are several values with the same file name  on the destination table (images table) in this case the name from the credits table could be copied to all the fields on the images table where that filename is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
  UPDATE Images, Credits  
    SET Images.image_restorer = Credits.credit_restorer 
    WHERE  Images.image_media_file = Credit.credit_file_name
```

This will toss an error if there is more than one `credit_restorer` for a distinct `credit_file_name` since MySQL won't know which `credit_restorer` it should use for the update. But it sounds like that might not be a problem in your case.

Comment: ok, thanks for the reply, but will it update any, all or none of the fields? Another question, I asked the question in reverse order, the destination table is the images table and the source is the credits table. Does this makes a difference on your answer?

Comment: Your code worked. I used because it had the syntax that was most familiar to me (I could understand it better) Thank you very much for the help. I´m not sure if I should mark this answer as the right one since the other answers may also be good...?

Answer (score 2):

You can use also Update join

```
UPDATE Images 
JOIN Credits Images.image_media_file = Credit.credit_file_name 
SET Images.image_restorer = Credits.credit_restorer
```

For the "Reverse order" like in you comment you should

```
UPDATE Credits
JOIN Images Images.image_media_file = Credit.credit_file_name 
SET Credits.image_restorer = Images.credit_restorer
```

Comment: In the opening post I asked the question in the reverse order of what I really need, I asked "...copy a value from table "images" to table "credits" if..." and what I meant is "...copy a value from table "credits" to table "images" if..." This makes a difference for the solution you provided doesn´t it?

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: ok, I thank you for your reply but since I used the answer below I´ll mark it as the accepted one. Sorry about that but thanks!

Comment: OK no problem is right  mark the answer you have used

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
    update Images INNER JOIN Credits ON credit_file_name=image_media_file SET 
    Images.image_restorer=Credits.credit_restorer
```

INNER JOIN: Returns all rows when there is at least one match in BOTH tables

LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, and the matched rows from the right table

RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, and the matched rows from the left table

FULL JOIN: Return all rows when there is a match in ONE of the tables

Comment: Thanks for the reply, would you put this expression in words, I´m not getting the INNER JOIN idea, my ignorance.